# Javascript requests slow or freezing pages

Tags: javascript

Typical Code looks this when doing javascript requests. The javascript is slow or it causes the page to freeze

```
length = dealerCards.length;

for (dealerCount = 0; dealerCount < length; dealerCount++) {
  newCard = dealerCards[dealerCount]
  var cardToDisplay = newCard.cardFaceDown;

  dealerIdName = 'BD';
  dealerIdName = dealerIdName + dealerCount.toString();
  fileNameCard = '<img  width="80" height="128" src="game/images/' + (cardToDisplay.trim()) + '" alt="Card"/>';
  document.getElementById(dealerIdName).innerHTML = fileNameCard;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over the array, and in each iteration trying to load the image in the page, but essentially you end up showing the last image in the page, as you're assigning `fileNameCard` to the `innerHTML` in the last line of the loop block.

The time it will take is directly proportional to the length of the array `dealerCards`, as you're modifying the DOM in a loop.

Instead, if the intent is to show all the images, try to push the tags to an array first and then assign it to `innerHTML` by joining the elements.

```
var htmlArray = [];

for ( ... ) {
  // ... code truncated for brevity
  htmlArray.push(fileNameCard);
} 

document.getElementById(dealerIdName).innerHTML = htmlArray.join('');
```

It will take significantly less time as it needs to update the DOM once. On the other hand, if the intent is to assign only the last image to the `innerHTML`, you should remove this line from the loop block:

```
document.getElementById(dealerIdName).innerHTML = fileNameCard;
```

And assign it when the loop ends:

```
var fileNameCard = // get the last element of the array and prepare the tag here
document.getElementById(dealerIdName).innerHTML = fileNameCard;
```